# How to store the others option value and dropdown selected value based on the selected one in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am new to ruby on rails, here i do hava drop down select box in that
>   few options if i select any one of that it should be store, incase if
>   i selected  others means one more text box should be appear and that
>   value should be store in the database
>
> ezetabs_controller.rb

```
def create
        @ezetab = Ezetab.new(ezetab_params)
        if @ezetab.save
            redirect_to @ezetab
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def ezetab_params
       ep = params.require(:ezetab).permit(:name, :email, :phonenumber, :organization, :city)
       ep[:city] = params[:others] if params[:others].present? 
       ep            
    end
```

> ezetab.rb

```
validates :city, presence: true
```

> new.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-2" id="mainone">
                    <%#= form.text_field :city, placeholder: "CITY", class: 'form-control required' %>
                    <%= form.select :city, options_for_select([['DELHI'],['GURGAON'],['FARIDABAD'],['GHAZIABAD'],['NOIDA'],['MUMBAI'],['THANE'], ['BANGALORE'],['OTHERS']]), {include_blank: 'CITY*'}, class: 'form-control required', name: 'city', :onchange => 'Checkselectedone(this.value);' %>
                        <% if @ezetab.errors[:city].present? %>
                            <span class="error_msg"><%= @ezetab.errors[:city][0]%></span>
                        <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <%#= form.text_field :others, "", id: 'newtext',style: 'display:none;' %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :others, "", class: 'form-control', id: 'newtext', style: 'display:none;' %>

                </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Checkselectedone(val){
    alert("one more text box is coming");
 var element=document.getElementById('newtext');
 if(val=='OTHERS')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}
```

> can any one let me know that how to store the dropdown selected one
>   because i can able to store only other oprtion text_field only
>   selected drop down i am unable to select please let me know, since i
>   am donig from yesterday to finish this one,   thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
ezetabs_controller.rb

def create

    if params[:ezetab][:others] != nil
      eze_params = ezetab_params.merge!(city: params[:ezetab][:others])
    else
      eze_params = ezetab_params
    end

    @ezetab = Ezetab.new(eze_params)
    if @ezetab.save
        redirect_to @ezetab
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end



private

def ezetab_params
   ep = params.require(:ezetab).permit(:name, :email, :phonenumber, :organization, :city)                  
end
```